# What is the meaning of Izquierdo's ending statement?

Tags: meaning, french-language, emmanuel-robles, montserrat

In the very end (Act III, Scene 11) of Emmanuel Roblès's play *Montserrat*, Izquierdo replies to Father Coronil's, after asking if he had regretted his decision:

> <sub>ENGLISH:</sub>
>
> No. He only talked to me about the joy of others!
>
> <sub>FRENCH:</sub>
>
> Non. Il me parlait seulement de la joie des autres !

What did he mean by this exactly?